# ¿Cómo dibujar un rectángulo sobre una imagen ya cargada con PIL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagen, tkinter, cv2

Estoy intentando conseguir dibujar un rectángulo sobre una imagen ya precargada con las coordenadas que apunta el ratón (apretar, soltar) Ya tengo conseguido recuperar las coordenadas de la zona con el puntero del ratón, pero no consigo dibujarlo, en realidad no sé me ocurre cómo... 
Lo que en realidad quiero es crear una sombra en la zona marcada con el ratón sobre esa parte de la imagen, que tengo cargada en un formulario Tkinter. Es sólo para remarcar la zona, no tiene ninguna función añadida.

Este es mi código:

```
##################################################################
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Aug  7 17:33:14 2018

@author: Usuario
"""
import pytesseract 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
import cv2
import time
import pickle
import os
coor1d=[]
coor2d=[]

event2canvas = lambda e, c: (c.canvasx(e.x), c.canvasy(e.y))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()

    #setting up a tkinter canvas with scrollbars
    frame = Frame(root, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    xscroll = Scrollbar(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    xscroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)
    yscroll = Scrollbar(frame)
    yscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
    canvas = Canvas(frame, bd=0, xscrollcommand=xscroll.set, yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
    xscroll.config(command=canvas.xview)
    yscroll.config(command=canvas.yview)
    frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

    #adding the image
    File = askopenfilename(parent=root, initialdir="M:/",title='Choose an image.')

    pick0=open("string.pickle","wb")
    pickle.dump(File,pick0)
    pick0.close()
    time.sleep(1)
    #print("opening %s" % File)
    img = PhotoImage(file=File)
    canvas.create_image(0,0,image=img,anchor="nw")
    canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))

    #function to be called when mouse is clicked
    def printcoords_1(event):
        #outputting x and y coords to console
        cx, cy = event2canvas(event, canvas)
        #print ("(%d, %d) / (%d, %d)" % (event.x,event.y,cx,cy))

        coor1d.append(int(cx))            
        coor1d.append(int(cy))            
        pick1=open("list.pickle","wb")
        pickle.dump(coor1d,pick1)
        pick1.close()
    def printcoords_2(event):
        #outputting x and y coords to console
        cx, cy = event2canvas(event, canvas)
        #print ("(%d, %d) / (%d, %d)" % (event.x,event.y,cx,cy))

        coor2d.append(int(cx))            
        coor2d.append(int(cy))            
        pick2=open("list.pickle","wb")
        pickle.dump(coor2d,pick2)
        pick2.close()      



    #mouseclick event
    canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>",printcoords_1)
    canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",printcoords_2)



    root.mainloop()

    img_crop2=img[coor1d[1]:coor2d[1],coor1d[0]:coor2d[0]]
    os.chdir('C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop')
    cv2.imwrite('contas99.png', img_crop2)
    time.sleep(2)

    img = Image.open('C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\contas99.png')
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
    print (result)
```

Comment: Hola Jose, deberías agregar un [mcve] para poder basarnos en algo y que la respuestas se adapten a tu código concreto. Si usas tkinter (por cierto añade la etiqueta `tkinter` junto a la general `python`) ¿Qué widget usas para mostrar  la imagen?¿Cómo obtienes las coordenadas del click?¿La idea es crear un rectángulo centrado en las coordenadas donde haces click de un tamaño predeterminado o algo similar a un  [drag-select](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/d/dragsele.htm)? La pregunta me parece interesante, a ver si la puedes mejorar y llegamos a algo. Un saludo.

Comment: Este es el codigo que tengo... funcionar funciona..  Lo que hago es recortar la imagen y pasarle el OCR para que lea la región, lo del rectángulo es por dale algo de "colorido"...

Comment: import pytesseract 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

Comment: from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
import cv2
import time
import pickle
import os
coor1d=[]
coor2d=[]

Comment: event2canvas = lambda e, c: (c.canvasx(e.x), c.canvasy(e.y))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()

    #setting up a tkinter canvas with scrollbars
    frame = Frame(root, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

Comment: scroll = Scrollbar(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    xscroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)
    yscroll = Scrollbar(frame)
    yscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
    canvas = Canvas(frame, bd=0, xscrollcommand=xscroll.set, yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
    xscroll.config(command=canvas.xview)
    yscroll.config(command=canvas.yview)
    frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

Comment: lo siento.. soy un patán!

Comment: la idea es sombrear la zona seleccionda... como si puede hacer con el paint... o el pdf creo..

Comment: No te preocupes hombre, a todos nos cuesta entender el sitio cuando empezamos. Para formatear el código solo tienes que copiarlo y pegarlo, luego seleccionas todo el código que acabas de pegar y pulsas `Ctrl`+ `k` o el botón `{}` del editor, con eso se formatea correctamente. Lo he editado, mira a ver si está correcto y es así como lo tienes por si he metido la pata, creo que lo tenías duplicado.

Comment: te faltan las ultimas lineas...

Comment: donde corto (que uso las cooord) , guardo y paso el OCR..

Comment: y acabo con un print (result) .. como no??!! ;-))

Comment: asi es el codigo entero.. gracias!!

Comment: se me ocurre superponer un layer transparente sobre la imagen... sigo "pergeñando"

Comment: Hola Jose, lo siento,  no he tenido mucho tiempo estos días.... He creado una respuesta, a ver si va en el sentido de lo que buscas o me he perdido totalmente.... Si buscas algo diferente comenta, si quieres marcar la zona de la imagen permanentemente, es sencillo de hacer con PiLL. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no me equivoco, lo que intentas hacer es seleccionar una zona de la imagen con el ratón, para poder obtener las coordenadas de la zona marcada y realizar un recortado de la misma (que luego le pasas al OCR) y la idea sería poder resaltar la zona de selección.

Para seleccionar y marcar una parte de una imagen cargada en un Canvas la idea podría ser dibujar un rectángulo en el mismo:

- Partimos de un contenedor encargado de almacenar las coordenadas `x` e `y`   del punto superior izquierdo del rectángulo y otro para las coordenadas `x` e `y` del punto inferior derecho del mismo. Gran parte del trabajo será ir actualizando estos puntos.
- Creamos una callback enlazada al evento `"<Button-1>"` que se encargará de inicializar uno de los vértices del rectángulo al pulsar el botón izquierdo del ratón sobre el canvas.
- Otra callback será asociada a `"<B1-Motion>"` (arrastre del puntero manteniendo pulsado el botón izquierdo). Esta nos va a servir para actualizar el segundo vértice e ir redibujando el rectángulo según se va arrastrando el puntero.
- Una tercera callback se asocia a`"<ButtonRelease-1>"` (soltar botón izquierdo del ratón). En ella hacemos las correcciones necesarias al rectángulo de selección, principalmente asegurarnos de que no excede los límites de la imagen y normalizar los vértices para que independientemente de la dirección en la que se creara el rectángulo uno sea siempre el superior izquierdo y otro el inferior derecho. Esto es importante a la hora de mandar las coordenadas a la función encargada de recortar la imagen.

Además de la idea general anterior, dos puntos a tener en cuenta:

- Para mostrar un rectángulo transparente (solo el borde) no hay problema, pero si queremos "sombrear" la zona seleccionada de la imagen la cosa se complica, una de las limitaciones de Tk es el no soporte de canal alpha para los colores, por lo que no podemos usar un rectángulo con relleno translucido...

  Podríamos trabajar con la imagen, sombreando esa zona, pero es un trabajo pesado para algo que es casi solo estético. Otra opción sería usar una segunda imagen semitransparente que podríamos escalar y superponer, pero también es complejo. Una opción, que aunque no semitransparencia, consigue un efecto similar es usar un mapa de bits con un patrón de punteado, tkinter trae algunos incluidos. Esto se consigue con la propiedad `stipple`:

  ```
  canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, fill="#18c194",
                          width=1, stipple="gray50"
                          )
  ```
- Cuando capturamos las coordenadas de los eventos, especialmente cuando se hace uso de las barras de desplazamiento previamente, es importante asegurarnos de que las coordenadas se corresponden con las coordenadas del canvas, no con las de la ventana. Si no tenemos en cuenta esto, pasaremos coordenadas incorrectas a la hora de recortar la imágen o dibujar el rectángulo de selección. Los métodos `canvasx` y `canvasy` de `tkinter.Canvas`nos permiten traducir de coordenadas de la ventana a coordenas del canvas.

Dejo un ejemplo funcional y reproducible implementando la idea anterior solo con Tkinter y Pillow (PILL). Se usa un enfoque procedural, acorde a la pregunta, pero lo suyo es envolver en una clase derivada de `Frame` tanto el canvas como las barras de desplazamiento y implementar en ella toda la funcionalidad:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


# Variables globales
_start = None    
_end = None
_img = None
_photo = None
_img_path = None
_funcids = {}


def _enable_croping():
    global canvas
    _funcids["<Button-1>"] = canvas.bind("<Button-1>", _on_click, '+')
    _funcids["<B1-Motion>"] = canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", _on_drag, '+')
    _funcids["<ButtonRelease-1>"] = canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", _on_drop, '+')

def _disable_croping():
    global canvas
    global crop_btn
    for event, funcid in _funcids.items():
        canvas.unbind(event, funcid)
    crop_btn.config(state="disabled")


def _open_image():
    global _img
    global _photo
    global _img_path
    global canvas

    file = askopenfilename(parent=root, initialdir="M:/",title='Choose an image.')
    if not file:
        return None

    canvas.delete("all")
    try:
        _img = Image.open(file)
    except OSError:
        _img = None
        _photo = None
        _img_path = None
        _disable_croping()
    else:
        _photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(_img)
        _img_path = file
        canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=_photo, anchor="nw", tags="image")
        _enable_croping()
    finally:
        canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(tk.ALL))


def _on_click(event):
    global _start
    global _end
    global canvas
    _start = (canvas.canvasx(event.x), canvas.canvasy(event.y))
    _end = None

def _on_drop(event):
    global _start
    global _end
    global _img
    global crop_btn

    if _end is None:
        crop_btn.config(state="disabled")

    else:

        # Acotar límites de seleción a la imagen
        img_x, img_y = _img.size

        x0, y0 = _start
        x0 = img_x if x0 > img_x else 0 if x0 < 0 else x0
        y0 = img_y if y0 > img_y else 0 if y0 < 0 else y0 
        _start = (x0, y0)

        x1, y1 = _end
        x1 = img_x if x1 > img_x else 0 if x1 < 0 else x1
        y1 = img_y if y1 > img_y else 0 if y1 < 0 else y1       
        _end = (x1, y1)

        # Normalizado para obtener vertice superior izquierdo e inferior derecho
        if x0 > x1:
            if y0 < y1: # _start es el vértice superior derecho
                _start = (x1, y0)
                _end = (x0, y1)
            else:       # _start es el vértice inferior derecho
                _start, _end = _end, _start
        else:
            if y0 > y1:  # _start es el vértice inferior izquierdo
                _start = (x0, y1)
                _end = (x1, y0)

        crop_btn.config(state="normal")

    # Redibujar rectágulo
    _draw_rectangle()



def _on_drag(event):
    global _start
    global _end
    global canvas

    x0, y0 = _start
    ex, ey = canvas.canvasx(event.x), canvas.canvasy(event.y)
    _end = (ex, ey)
    _draw_rectangle()


def _draw_rectangle():
    global canvas
    global _end
    global _start

    canvas.delete("rectangle")

    if _end is None or _start is None:    
        return None

    x0, y0 = _start
    x1, y1 = _end

    canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill="#18c194",
                            width=1, stipple="gray50", tags='rectangle'
                            )

def _crop_image():
    global _img
    global _start
    global _end
    # Recortado de la imagen 
    #print(_start, _end)
    cropped = _img.crop(_start + _end)
    cropped.show()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Recortar imagen")

# Frame contenedor con canvas y barras de desplazamiento
frame = tk.Frame(root, bd=2, relief=tk.SUNKEN)
xscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
yscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame)
canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, bd=0,
                   xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set
                   )
open_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Abrir imagen", command=_open_image)
crop_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Recortar imagen", state="disabled", command=_crop_image)


# Estructurando el widget
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")
xscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")
yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
open_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="ew")
crop_btn.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="nsew")

xscrollbar.config(command=canvas.xview)
yscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)


# Inicio del mainloop de la app
root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: chapeau, messier!!

Comment: que codigo tan limpio!

Comment: mi gustaria comentarte una cosa @FJ SEvilla, me puedes escribir a jmigueloneca@hotmail.com. Gracias!